# iPhone voicemail won't play

Tags: ios, voicemail

Using an iPhone 6, I received a call which went to voicemail, and the caller apparently left a message. I say "apparently" because when I go in to the voicemail app, the message won't play. If I click the "play" button/icon, the icon changes to the "pause" icon, but otherwise nothing happens and no sound plays. The progress bar shows a 32-second message, but it doesn't advance.

I exported the message to Voice Memos but that app exhibits the same behavior when attempting to play the file - the progress bar doesn't move, and no sound is played.

If this was just a normal audio file, I would guess the file is somehow corrupted (although apparently the metadata is OK). Are there any strategies I can use to try to recover the file or otherwise play the message?

Comment: Isn't the voicemail actually stored on the servers of the carrier?  Have you tried logging into your carrier's site or contacting them to retrieve the vm?

Comment: AT&T's dial-up vm number won't accept my PIN, even though I've gone through the process for re-setting it. There doesn't seem to be a provision for accessing voice messages on their customer service site, even when logged in.

Comment: You should contact AT&T directly, there seems to be a problem with your vm setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be something about my iPhone audio. A little later in the day I discovered that music wasn't playing. (Oddly, I was still getting sound effects from a game.) The music app would advance the progress bar on a song but produce no sound.

With that additional data, I rebooted the phone (full power down and power back up) and music would play and so would the voicemail. So whatever it was, it was software (because the power cycle cleared it).